# Scala "operator" methods invoking with reflection

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a trait with some math methods like sin, cos, and so on, with addition to standard operators: +, -, *.

Is there any way to invoke them with reflection? I'm trying to do it like this:

```
def apply(name: String)(args: Expression*) = {
  val im = mirror.reflect(objectReflectionInstance)
  val method = im.symbol.typeSignature.member(TermName(name))
  im.reflectMethod(method.asMethod)(args)
}

lazy val mirror = runtimeMirror(Environment.getClass.getClassLoader)

lazy val objectReflectionInstance = {
  val module = mirror.staticModule("interpreter.Environment")
  mirror.reflectModule(module).instance
}
```

and it works for "cos", "sin" but it does now work for "+", "*". I think it's caused by scala transforming the method name underneath to something else, but there still should be a way to call them "dynamically".

Comment: I think you're right about the translation. Have you tried `$plus` and `$times`? See this blog post: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was hoping to achieve this without a string mapping, but it seems this is the only way.

Comment: Using *Java* reflection would certainly need to use the mangled names, because obviously Java doesn't know about the "real" names, but one of the benefits of Scala having its *own* reflection system, built on top of the Scala compiler and *independent* from Java's should be that we are not restricted by what is and isn't a legal name in Java, right? At least that's what I would assume!

Comment: That's what I was assuming, but unfortunately it does not work as we would like it to work. For now simple name mapping works in my case.